# map max efficient insert

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert

Here is some working code:

```
std::pair<typename std::map< time_t, T >::iterator, bool> ret;    
ret = prt_map->insert ( std::pair< time_t, T >( seconds , value ) );
if (ret.second == false) // exists
{
 ... update exising value
}
```

I want to upgrade it to max efficient inserting code and give a tip to insert that need to start from --prt_map->end(); something like:

```
  prt_map->insert ( --prt_map->end(), std::pair< time_t, T >( seconds , value ) );
```

but this insert function prototupe does not return std::pair with bool that notify that value added or not ( to check for existing and update if so... How to solve this to have ability to update existing value?

Comment: For maximum efficiency you probably want to use a hash table (e.g. `std::unordered_map`).

Comment: @n-m i can not always use new gcc, therefore unordered_map can be unsupported on the system when i will compile the program.

Comment: `boost::unordered_map` is supported almost everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post condition of a.insert(hint, t) is:

> a contains an element whose key is the same as that of t. The size of a is incremented by either 1 or 0.

which should be sufficient information to determine whether or not the element was inserted.

Comment: nice. but the question now is what is more efficient, my first function, or function that will request and store previous size value, then request new size value + compare.

Answer (score 0):

The second version (just like the first) does not update the value if the key already exists.  You can check whether it was indeed updated/inserted:

```
std::map<time_t, T>::iterator ret = prt_map->insert(--prt_map->end(),
    std::make_pair(seconds, value));
if (*ret != value) {
   // the same key already exists, update value
   *ret = value;
}
```

This assumes you have `operator!=()` defined on the value type

Comment: you check for the same value, but its can be other. need to check the key. and update only if the key the same.

Comment: The key in the returned iterator _will_be_ the one you wanted to associate the value with, but the value will only be the same if it has been newly inserted or if the already exisiting value associated with the key happens to be the same as the one you wanted to insert